# What files can I delete after making .exe file with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

What files can I delete after creating .exe file with pyinstaller in order not to damage the application?

The directory contains:

```
.idea/
__pycache__/
build/
dist/
venv/
main.py
main.spec
```

...as also shown in this graphical listing:

[image: Graphical directory listing]

Comment: BTW, please try to include data in textual form -- screenshots shouldn't be relied on in questions for the reasons given in [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122). I've edited towards that effect here.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete `build` and `dist`, after you got the exe out. `__pycache__` is created by python every time you run the application.

Answer (score 0):

back up your .exe file inside the Dist folder and then delete Build and Dist folder along with any .spec files.

To make your application run professionally always use --windowed command along with other commands that you are using like:

in the Terminal type:
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --add-data "image1.png:." --add-data "picture2.jpeg:." --icon=image.ico main.py

or
in windows CMD type:
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data "image1.png:." --add-data "picture2.jpeg:." --icon=image.ico main.py

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may delete these files as they are auto-generated by `pyinstaller` for all platforms: `build` `main.spec`, as well as `.DS_Store` for macOS, and `__pycache__` which is generated every time a module is imported.