# Pyinstaller exe file severity

Tags: python, discord.py, pyinstaller

## Ive been using pyinstaller for awhile.

### I am making a discord.py discord bot (yes i know its discontinued but still works so eh) and I need to obfubiscate my code so I can share it to other people. (run it on their own computer)

###### Some answers that ive lurked through have been helpful, but all i need to know is the `filename.spec` file crucial or can i remove it?

###### Mine **in detail** reveals some important information the consumer of my code shouldnt know. If there is anyway i can make it invisible to the normal person, that would work.

###### But for now its vulnerable and I don't know the severity of me deleting it.

### Why do I need to know:

- I have my information gathered mostly from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111650/what-files-can-i-delete-after-making-exe-file-with-pyinstaller).
- [Pyinstaller's docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) did not help me.
- I cannot manage to hide my code from people that will steal it. As I have api keys for [giphy](https://developers.giphy.com/), [youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3), and a [random api](https://www.random.org/) that I *paid for*.

> Please note I am not using youtube for music I understand the ban and how music bots are coming to a close.

Comment: PyInstaller will **not** encrypt your code. It's still right there and trivial to extract

Comment: then what can i use to obfubiscate my code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code-from-being-read-by-users

Comment: i checked that exact thing, it only worked for about 1 - 2 files, so with cogs and me having text files, json files, and folders, its basically impossible.